# C# есть ли какой-то способ взять из базы List<int> и добавить значения в другой List<int>

Tags: c#

Как это вообще делается в c#?
Нужно чтоб значения попадали в список из базы
Мне представляется это так

```
List<int> nums = new List<int> (); 
   foreach () {
  Здесь разбивается база и каждая
   Циферка добавляется в список
    Nums.Add(int)
}
```

Если способ сделать это изящнее?

Comment: [.AddRange()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: EvgeniyZ, // Add a range of items  
string[] authors = { "Mike Gold", "Don Box",  
                        "Sundar Lal", "Neel Beniwal" };  
AuthorList.AddRange(authors);

Comment: Такое типа нагуглил, но удалять вопросец не стал,

Comment: Это лучший вариант правиль?

Comment: Default locale, да нет, меня Евгений понял, это ожидаемый видимо был вопрос после моего предыдущего вопроса)))) вот не спится то а)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать  класс Number добавить свойство _number типа int и запрашивать из базы.

```
//Код предназначен для примера 

            string getNumbersQuery= "SELECT number FROM Numbers";

            using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(getNumbersQuery, connection))
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var entity = new Numbers
                    {
                        _number = reader.GetInt16/32/64(0),

                    };

                    result.Add(entity);
                }
            }
public class Numbers
    {
        public int _number{ get; set; }
}
```